# Referring to Class instantiater in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, this

I have this method of a JavaScript class that I've created:

```
resetRule() {
  let sheetRules = Array.from(this.sheet.rules);
  sheetRules.forEach(function(node, i) {
    if(node.name != undefined) {
      newRule.sheet.deleteRule(i);
    }
  });
}
```

when you instantiate a `class`, it essentially has to be set to a variable, like so:

```
const newRule = new NewRule(*params*);
```

and the methods/properties of said `class` can refer to the class *object* using `this.` like so:

```
this.method();
this.property;
```

What I'd like to know is: how does one refer back to the *variable* that instantiated the class within a *function* that is called by a *method* of said class?

To be even clearer: a function that is called within a method of a class alters the scope, which also means it alters the definition of `this.`. My question is: *how do you get around this?* **How could you access the variable that instantiated the `class` when you are out the of scope of the methods within said `class`?**

---

As I was composing this question, I realized that you can set the `this` value for a `.forEach` loop like this:

```
resetRule() {
  let sheetRules = Array.from(this.sheet.rules);
  sheetRules.forEach(function(node, i) {
    if(node.name != undefined) {
      this.sheet.deleteRule(i);
    }
  }, this);
}
```

However, the way this code works is something that--as far as I know--is just a benefit of the `.forEach` method, and I'd still like to know how it should be handled in general.

Comment: "`the methods/properties of said class can refer to the class object using this`" — `this` refers to the local instance of that class

Comment: @vol7ron yeesss.. buuuuuut, if `this.method()` contains a function and you want to try to use `this` to refer to said 'instance' within that function, it doesn't work. Hence the question...

Comment: I may need you to prove that

Comment: You can just do `let foo = this`, maybe this is what you need

Comment: @Lux would that be in the constructor? like: `class NewClass { constructor(a, b) { this.a = a; this.b = b; let foo = this } }`? or would it be just arbitrarily placed, like, between methods or something?

Comment: How are you calling the method.  Whenever you do `instance.method()`, `this` will be set to the class instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a temporary variable called `self` or something which would allow you to use both the object containing "this" instance as well as within that anonymous function passed to forEach, `this` which will refer to `sheetRules` when you don't specify another variable to use as `this`

```
resetRule() {
  let sheetRules = Array.from(this.sheet.rules);
  let self = this;
  sheetRules.forEach(function(node, i) {
    if(node.name != undefined) {
    self.sheet.deleteRule(i);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this should help you out, using your example.

```js
class Rule {
  constructor(rules) {
    this.sheet = {
      rules: rules || []
    }
  }
  
  log(){
    console.log('rules:',this.sheet.rules)
  }
  
  resetRule() {
    let sheetRules = Array.from(this.sheet.rules);
    let self = this;       // <-- here you can capture the instance
    
    sheetRules.forEach(function(node, i) {
      self.log()           // <-- here you can use it in forEach   
      if (node.name != undefined)
        this.sheet.deleteRule(i);
    });
  }
}
const fooRule = new Rule(['foo'])
const barRule = new Rule(['bar'])

fooRule.resetRule()
barRule.resetRule()

fooRule.log()
barRule.log()
```

Your *forEach* works because as you discovered, you passed *this* as an argument for the *thisArg* parameter.  However, if you didn't, you could have just as easily set it to a variable in the outer scope and used it in the block scope.

Generally creating a variable called *self* or *that* and setting it to *this* is helpful, especially for arrow functions, which set `this` to the encapsulating scope and not the instance object.

Comment: yup, this seems to be the general consensus. thank you sir. *to those who **marked as duplicate*** ya I figured that was gonna happen, but as I said, I didn't know how else to ask this question so... thanks for indirectly answering my question!!

Answer (score 0):

If I've not misunderstood you're looking for a way to retain your scope? You have a few options here.

The immediate answers would be to use [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) or [Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to specify the context of `this` when invoking those methods.

Alternatively you could just make the scope of your `this` available where needed:

```
var MyClass = function () {
    // Here we bind the local scope to a variable that will give us context where necessary.
    // While it's not needed here, it can give context and set a pattern of reability through repitition.
    var vm = this;

    vm.methodA = function () {
        // We continue to set our 'vm' pointer variable when needed.
        var vm = this;

        globalMethod.then(function () {
            // We're able to retain context of our `this` through having scope of our 'vm' variable.
            vm.methodB();
        });
    };

    vm.methodB = function () {
        console.log('I did stuff!');
    };
};
```